# SQL: summing a column starting from row immediately after two consecutive 'trigger' values in another column

Tags: sql, oracle

How to sum all values after two consecutive `YES`'s in the `CONDITION_SATISFIED` column?

```
ID | CONDITION_SATISFIED | VALUE
--------------------------------
 1 | NO                  |   100
 2 | NO                  |   300
 3 | NO                  |   500
 4 | YES                 |   100
 5 | YES                 |   300
 6 | NO                  |   500 <-
 7 | NO                  |   100 <-
 8 | YES                 |   300 <-
 9 | NO                  |   500 <-
--------------------------------
                     SUM |  1400
```

Note: further occurrences of YES/NO are ignored once the summation is started.

I've gotten to the point where I am able to generate two extra columns for the `CONDITION_SATISFIED` column like this:

```
ID | CONDITION_SATISFIED | VALUE     RANK | REPEAT_COUNT
--------------------------------     -------------------
 1 | NO                  |   100        1 |            3
 2 | NO                  |   300        1 |            3 
 3 | NO                  |   500        1 |            3 
 4 | YES                 |   100        2 |            2 
 5 | YES                 |   300        2 |            2 
 6 | NO                  |   500        3 |            2 <- start from here
 7 | NO                  |   100        3 |            2 
 8 | YES                 |   300        4 |            1 
 9 | NO                  |   500        5 |            1
--------------------------------     -------------------
```

But I'm not able to figure out how to get the first instance of `REPEAT_COUNT >= 2 AND CONDITION_SATISFIED = 'YES'`, and then start the summation immediately after the 2nd `YES` (as indicated).

Comment: Hello Hassaan, could you also include the desired output?

Comment: It's just the sum (shown at the bottom of the first table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . You can get the first where the two yesses are using `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(condition_satisfied) over (order by id) as prev_cs,
             lag(condition_satisfied, 2) over (order by id) as prev2_cs
      from t
     ) t
where prev2_cs = 'YES' and prev_cs = 'YES';
```

Then you can just use this in a query:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select min(t.id) as id
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(condition_satisfied) over (order by id) as prev_cs,
                   lag(condition_satisfied, 2) over (order by id) as prev2_cs
            from t
           ) t
      where prev2_cs = 'YES' and prev_cs = 'YES'
     ) yy
     on t.id >= yy.id;
```

Comment: Thank you! (I had to use `min(t.id)` in the innermost `select` to prevent duplicates when there are more than 2 consecutive `YES`'s)

Comment: There is a solution without generate/prevent duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle 12c: pattern matching

```
with t1 (id, condition_satisfied, value) as (
select 1, 'NO' , 100 from dual union all
select 2, 'NO' , 300 from dual union all
select 3, 'NO' , 500 from dual union all
select 4, 'YES', 100 from dual union all
select 5, 'YES', 300 from dual union all
select 6, 'NO' , 500 from dual union all
select 7, 'NO' , 100 from dual union all
select 8, 'YES', 300 from dual union all
select 9, 'NO' , 500 from dual)
select sum(v_value) as sum_value
from t1
match_recognize(
order by id
measures s.value as v_value
all rows per match
pattern (yes{2} s+)
define
yes   as condition_satisfied = 'YES'
);

 SUM_VALUE
----------
      1400
```

If you have version lower than 12 no need to self-join and generate/prevent duplicates:

```
with s (id, condition_satisfied, value) as (
select 1, 'NO' , 100 from dual union all
select 2, 'NO' , 300 from dual union all
select 3, 'NO' , 500 from dual union all
select 4, 'YES', 100 from dual union all
select 5, 'YES', 300 from dual union all
select 6, 'NO' , 500 from dual union all
select 7, 'YES' , 100 from dual union all
select 8, 'YES', 300 from dual union all
select 9, 'NO' , 500 from dual)
select sum(value) sum_value
from
   (select s.*, min(first_id) over () min_id
    from
       (select s.*,
        case when condition_satisfied = 'YES' and condition_satisfied = lag(condition_satisfied) over (order by id) then id end first_id
        from s
       ) s
   )
where id > min_id;

 SUM_VALUE
----------
      1400
```